# Binding ListBox and TextBoxes to Datatable

Tags: wpf, binding, datatable, textbox, listbox

I have this code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

            SqlConnection conn;
            DataTable dataTable;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;

            public MainWindow() {
                try {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    this.conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(LocalDB)\\v11.0; Database = usersdb; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
                    this.conn.Open();

                    this.dataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Forenames, Surname from users", conn);
                    new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                    adapter.Fill(this.dataTable);


this.DataContext = this.dataTable;

    TextBox textBox= new TextBox { };
                    Binding binding = new Binding("forenames");
                    binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                    binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
                    binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                    textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);


    }
```

I also have this in the XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="forenames" Name="listBox" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

How do I bind the textboxes to display the currently selected person in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Hi to display that info you need to define this in your `VM`

```
private DataRow _selectedPerson;
public DataRow SelectedPerson
{
    get { return _selectedPerson;}
    set { _selectedPerson = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");}
}
```

your `get` should return elements with names and surname and in your xaml

```
<ListBox ... SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPerson, Converter={StaticResource dtRow2Text}}"/>
```

and your `Converter`

```
public class DataRow2String: IValueConveter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object paramater, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dt = value as DataRow;
        return (dt[index with names] +" "+ dt[index with surname]).ToString();
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Okay, how do I achieve something like this: TextBox textb = new TextBox { Text = "Binding Path=Rows[2].ItemArray[2],Mode=Default}" }; or this: Binding binding = new Binding { Path=Rows[2]["forenames"]};

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I finally achieved it using:

```
private void selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            int index = this.listBox.SelectedIndex;
            if (index < 0 || index > this.dataTable.Rows.Count)
                return;            
            UIElementCollection collection = this.grid.Children;
           foreach (UIElement element in collection)
               if (element is TextBox) {
                   TextBox t = (TextBox)element;
                   t.DataContext = this.dataTable.DefaultView[index];
               }
        }
```

Comment: kk but please note that selectionChanged() will not be invoked when you will have one item in the colelction.